# Как выключить/включить звук у видио по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, видео

Добрый день уважаемые. Вопрос - как инициализировать кнопку по нажатию на которую у видио файла будет отключатся звук? Вот на этом примере

```js
$(".button_voice").on("click", function() {

  $(this).toggleClass("button_voice__mute button_voice__noisy");

  if ($(this).hasClass("button_voice__mute")) {
    $('#video-item').attr("muted", "muted");
  } else {
    $('#video-item').removeAttr("muted");
  }


});
```

```css
.main-page__video {
  max-width: 400px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.main-page__slide {
  width: 33%;
}

.video-wrap {
  background: #b25e25;
  padding-bottom: 78.56%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.main-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  opacity: .48;
}

.discount {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 64rem;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  font-family: LCChalk, sans-serif;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 20%;
  left: -1%;
}

.video-bord__ico {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 46px;
  width: 54px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-image: url(../img/ico/hesh.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  right: 17px;
  bottom: 19px;
}

.button_voice {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 5;
}

.button_voice__noisy:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* прописывай стили для кнопки со звуком*/
  background-color: #0f0;
}

.button_voice__mute:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* прописывай стили для кнопки без звука*/
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button_voice button_voice__noisy"></button>
<video class="main-video" controls id="video-item">
       <source src="http://mimi.webstars.com.ua/img/video/videoTest.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;">
      </video>
```

По нажатию на зеленую/красную кнопку звук у видио ролика должен пропадать/возникать. В атрибуты к видио вроде как прописывается muted="muted" но я не могу понять почему оно не срабатывает ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что надо использовать не `attr`, а `prop`.

```js
$(".button_voice").on("click", function() {
  var isMuted =
    $(this)
      .toggleClass("button_voice__mute button_voice__noisy")
      .hasClass("button_voice__mute");
  
  $('#video-item').prop("muted", isMuted);
});
```

```css
/* CSS не изменён и не имеет отношения к проблеме */
.main-page__video { max-width: 400px; padding-right: 15px; margin: auto; position: relative; z-index: 9; } .main-page__slide { width: 33%; } .video-wrap { background: #b25e25; padding-bottom: 78.56%; position: relative; overflow: hidden; margin-left: -15px; } .main-video { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; -o-object-fit: cover; object-fit: cover; display: block; opacity: .48; } .discount { position: absolute; font-size: 64rem; -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); transform: rotate(-45deg); font-family: LCChalk, sans-serif; z-index: 4; top: 20%; left: -1%; } .video-bord__ico { position: absolute; display: block; height: 46px; width: 54px; border: 1px solid #000; background-image: url(../img/ico/hesh.png); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; right: 17px; bottom: 19px; } .button_voice { position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 20px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: none; border: none; cursor: pointer; z-index: 5; } .button_voice__noisy:after { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; content: ""; width: 100%; height: 100%; /* прописывай стили для кнопки со звуком*/ background-color: #0f0; } .button_voice__mute:after { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; content: ""; width: 100%; height: 100%; /* прописывай стили для кнопки без звука*/ background-color: #f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button_voice button_voice__noisy"></button>
<video class="main-video" controls id="video-item">
  <source src="http://mimi.webstars.com.ua/img/video/videoTest.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;">
</video>
```